# How to solve FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory for Python 3.7/Mac

Tags: python, macos

Details:

Python 3.7.1, Mac OS High Sierra 10.13.6. I am using IDLE and running the program through the terminal. I recently had success with the MNIST handwritten numbers and now I am trying to train a Generative Adversarial Network with my own dataset. The dataset is a folder of images.

The error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Pride.py", line 29, in <module>
    listing = os.listdir(path1) 
   FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'Users/darren/Desktop/Pride'
```

I have looked at other threads on this issue but don't understand what's wrong with my path so I apologise if my error is due to something simple. The Python file that I'm executing from the terminal and my dataset folder are both on my Desktop.

Here is my code up until this point:

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers.core import Dense, Dropout, Activation, Flatten
from keras.layers.convolutional import Convolution2D, MaxPooling2D
from keras.optimizers import SGD,RMSprop,adam
from keras.utils import np_utils
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib
import os
import theano
from PIL import Image
from numpy import *
from sklearn.utils import shuffle
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

# input image dimensions
img_rows, img_cols = 200, 200

# number of channels
img_channels = 1

#%%
#  data

path1 = "Users/darren/Desktop/Pride" #path of folder of images    
path2 = "Users/darren/Desktop/Prideresized"  #path of folder to save images
listing = os.listdir(path1) 
num_samples=size(listing)
print ("num_samples")

for file in listing:
    im = Image.open(path1 + '\\' + file)   
    img = im.resize((img_rows,img_cols))
    gray = img.convert('L')
    gray.save(path2 +'\\' +  file, "JPEG")
```

Comment: Your `path1` variable is a relative path. It is likely that your program's view of what the current working directory is, isn't what you think it is. Start by specifying an absolute path to check that that works. That will suggest a solution to the problem. (And, lower down, are you sure you want a backslash between folder and filename?)

Comment: Thanks BoarGules. Why is that backslash there? I'm just using someone else's code. Should I remove the backslash? 
Edit: Oh, it should be forward slash, right?

Comment: It looks like Windows-specific code to me.  Windows uses \ to separate elements of filenames where OSX uses /. Now Windows is usually bright enough to translate any / it sees in filenames to \ but I don't know enough about OSX to tell if you can rely on something similar.The platform-independent way to do it is to use `os.path.sep`.

Answer (score 1):

in mac os, if you save the file of your dataset or any other file in the documents folder then code for the path of that file may be like this

```
melbourne_file_path = **'/Users/adi/Documents/Top250.csv'**
melbourne_data = pd.read_csv(melbourne_file_path) 
melbourne_data.describe()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using relative paths (a path that does not start with a `/`) you need to change them so they are relative to your script's location.

In your case:

```
path1 = "Pride" #path of folder of images    
path2 = "Prideresized"  #path of folder to save images
```